# How not to show 0´s in label?

Tags: ios, swift

I have some buttons that print some text in a label when pushed. I also have a counter in front of the text to show how many times the respective button is pushed. But if some of the buttons isn´t pushed, it shows 0 in the label. Is it possible to convert the initial value on the int to blank space?
I have tried something like this:

```
var addCount:int = 0

var blankSpace = ""

if addCount == 0 {
addcount = blankSpace
}
else {
....
}
```

I have also tried:

```
if addCount == 0 {
addCount = String (blankSpace)
}
else {
}
```

and I have tried:

```
if addCount == 0 {
addCount = String ("")
}
```

I´m probably going about this all wrong, and I would appreciate help with this.
*
*
*

**Edit: I thought there was some magic trick in swift to make the 0 disappear, so I took some shortcuts when I asked my question. Here is the whole setup:**
I have four buttons in View Controller 1 that prints some text and adds 1 to counter. The data is based through a Swift file **allSum**.
The label that displays the text and counter is in View Controller 2.

**allSum:**

```
import UIKit


class allSum: NSObject {
    var btn1Pressed:String = ""
    var addToBtn1:Int = 0
    var btn2Pressed:String = ""
    var addToBtn2:Int = 0
    var btn3Pressed:String = ""
    var addToBtn3:Int = 0
    var btn4Pressed:String = ""
    var addToBtn4:Int = 0

      func printToLabel() -> String{ //return a string with the current status
        return ("\(addToBtn1) \(btn1Pressed + "")") + ("\(addToBtn2) \(btn2Pressed + "")") + ("\(addToBtn3) \(btn3Pressed + "")") + ("\(addToBtn4) \(btn4Pressed + "")")

        }
```

**View Controller 1**

```
var total = allSum

var button1 = "Button 1 Pressed\n"    
var button2 = "Button 2 Pressed\n"    
var button3 = "Button 3 Pressed\n"    
var button4 = "Button 4 Pressed\n"     

@IBAction func no1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    total.btn1Pressed = button1  
    toal.addToBtn1 += 1 
    }

@IBAction func no2(_ sender: UIButton) {
     total.btn2Pressed = button2   
     toal.addToBtn2 += 1 
     }    

@IBAction func no3(_ sender: UIButton) {
     total.btn3Pressed = button3  
     toal.addToBtn3 += 1 
     }    

@IBAction func no4(_ sender: UIButton) {
     total.btn4Pressed = button4   
     toal.addToBtn4 += 1
     }
```

**View Controller 2**

```
var total = allSum?    

label.text = total.printToLabel()
```

With this setup, the label is showing 0 0 0 0 when no buttons are pressed.

So, my problem is that I can't set the `label.text = ""` since I also have other variables printed to it.

Sorry for my initial laziness

Comment: Where's your code for setting the label's text?

Comment: @rmaddy I have edited my question with the whole setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the actual label text as a blank space.

```
var addCount:Int = 0
var blankSpace = ""

if addCount == 0 {
    yourlabel.text = blankSpace
} else {
    yourlabel.text = "\(addCount)"
}
```

UPDATED:
Here's a way to write your current code with less code and fix your issue of changing 0's to blank strings

**AllSum**

```
class AllSum {

    var sumsArray: [Int] = [0,0,0,0]

    func stringForLabel() -> String { //return a string with the current status
        var string = ""

        for (index, value) in self.sumsArray.enumerated() {
            if value > 0 {
                string = string + "\(value) Button \(index + 1) was pressed\n"
            }
        }
        return string
    }
}
```

**View Controller 1**

You can use tags in UIBuilder, to match the indices in your array. Link up all buttons to the same function

```
var total = AllSum()

@IBAction func numberPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    total.sumsArray[sender.tag] = sumsArray[sender.tag] + 1  
}
```

**View Controller 2**

```
var total = AllSum()
label.text = total.stringForLabel()
```

Comment: I also have other variables printed to the label, so I cannot set the whole label to "" I have edited my initial question with the whole setup

Comment: But all of your code could be rewritten if you are trying to do it with less code. Your ViewController1 code could be changed to 1 function instead of 4 since they all essential do the same thing - you could use tags on your buttons to know which one is being pressed. Your allSum class could be built with an array and and a function rather than 4 strings and 4 ints.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to assign a string, i.e. `""`, to a variable you've declared as an `Int`.  In this case you'd be better off dealing with this at the time that you set the text on the label.  You can use a simple if/else statement, or a ternary operator if you want a one-liner:

```
if addCount == 0 {
  self.label.text = ""
} else {
  self.label.text = "\(addCount)"
}
```

And for the ternary option:

```
self.label.text = addCount == 0 ? "" : "\(addCount)"
```

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks - I corrected this.  I missed it in the first read.

Comment: I also have other variables printed to the label, so I cannot set the whole label to "" I have edited my initial question with the whole setup

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to set an Int to a String. Swift is a type safe language and doesn't let you do that. If you need, for some reason, to have the same variable represent both states, you can use an enum with an associated value and still use it as long as it is `Describable`.

Instead you can just have a computed value that returns a String that returns a blank String if the variable is zero:

```
func displayCount () -> String {
 return addCount == 0 ? String() : String(describing:addCount)
}
```